# How to get from Iceland to Greenland?

Tags: air-travel, ferries, iceland, greenland

I'm planning to go to Iceland this summer. Since I've never been so close to Greenland before (except on a plane), I'm thinking about going to Greenland too. Is there any ferry or plane that goes from Iceland to Greenland? If yes, how much time will this need? How much does it cost?

Comment: Any thoughts to going when there's darkness? I'm keen to go as well but for the northern lights - and yes, I want to do both land-masses ;)

Comment: Some years ago, there was a ferry, but now I'm unable to find info about it :(

Comment: Are you a strong swimmer?

Comment: not more than 50 meters..

Comment: I've been to iceland by ferry a few years ago, I'm still planning to go back. You can easily travel around the whole island in one week by car (we even used a normal roadcar, you'll see why that was insane). Just follow road 1 and if you don't have a proper 4x4 DO NOT TAKE THE REDIRECTIONS, we learned the hard way and finding a tyre dealer in iceland is HARD.

Comment: Any chance you'd be keen in say, March? :)

Comment: Greenland Tourism [notes](http://www.greenland.com/en/plan-your-trip/how-to-get-to-greenland/): *Some shipping companies also sail from the USA and Canada or a country in Europe.*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the official [Greenland tourism site](http://www.greenland.com/en/explore-greenland.aspx) there are two places you can use as your source.  Rejkjavik and Copenhagen.  There are 2 airlines servicing the island: [Air Iceland](http://www.airiceland.is) and [Air Greenland](http://www.airgreenland.com).  The price Air Iceland is currently quoting for destinations in Greenland is 161 EUR (Kulusuk) and 193 EUR (Nuuk). I guess the further north the more expensive it gets since you will probably need a helicopter ride.

Could not find the ferries but there are cruises from Europe that will take you around Northern sites including Greenland.

There are multiple sites referring to that but they may be exactly the same cruise:

- http://www.polarcruises.com/arctic
- https://www.cruisenorway.com/explore/greenland-immersions

Comment: Hi karlson! There are two dead links here. The first is the Greenland Tourism. It looks like the page may have moved to [Visit Greenland](https://visitgreenland.com/), but I'm not sure. The same is true of Cruise Norway. The link is dead but it goes to the Cruise Norway site so that page may still exist at another part of the site! If you'd like to check them out and replace them, it would be really helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

For flights, you can arrive from three countries:

- From Iceland, through Air Iceland and Air Greenland
- From Copenhagen, Denmark, with Air Greenland.
- from Iqaluit, Canada with Air Nunavut.

By boat to/from Nuuk (the capital):
 - Arctic Umiaq Line has a passenger terminal to Maniitsoq-Sisimiut-Aasiaat-Uummannaq and Paamiut-Qaqortoq-Narsaq-Narsarsuaq.

- Royal Arctic Line and Blue Water are cargo-boat companies operating out of Nuuk.

([Reference](http://wikitravel.org/en/Nuuk#Get_in))

Answer (score 5):

As of 2024, there are three airports in Iceland with direct flights to Greenland:

- From [Keflavík](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keflav%C3%ADk_International_Airport) (Iceland's main international airport, sometimes marketed as Reykjavík-Keflavík), you can fly to [Kulusuk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kulusuk_Airport) (Icelandair), [Nuuk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuuk_Airport) (Air Greenland or Icelandair), or [Ilullisat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilulissat_Airport) (Air Greenland or Icelandair). In some years there may also be (seasonal) flights to [Narsarsuaq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narsarsuaq_Airport) (Icelandair) (there were such flights in summer 2023). The Nuuk-Keflavík route is the only stable international route from Nuuk (some years I have seen flights to [Iqaluit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iqaluit_Airport) in Canada, but last time this route only ran for three years before closing again), although this may change when the new/expanded airport in Nuuk opens.
- From [Reykjavík](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reykjavik_Airport), there are flights to [Nerlerit Inaat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerlerit_Inaat_Airport) (Norlandair).  Flight time is 1 hour 45 minutes. These are the only international flights from Reykjavík.
- From [Akureyi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akureyri_Airport), you can fly to [Nerlerit Inaat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerlerit_Inaat_Airport) (Norlandair).  At less than 600 km, this is the shortest flight to Greenland.  Flight time is 1 hour 30 minutes.

Please note that Nerlerit Inaat is a very remote airport serving a community with only 15 inhabitants. Most travellers probably continue to [Ittoqqortoormiit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ittoqqortoormiit_Heliport), serving a settlement with 345 inhabitants, or join cruises or expeditions from Nerlerit Inaat. Neither Nerlerit Inaat nor Ittoqqortoormiit have direct connections to the rest of Greenland (only via Iceland), unless you fancy crossing the ice cap on foot (more than 1,000 km)...

The "major" Greenlandic airport of [Kangerlussuaq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kangerlussuaq_Airport) has only flights to Greenland and Denmark, not Iceland, probably because most Kangerlussuaq travellers want to continue to Nuuk or other Greenlandic destinations anyway, and those are served by direct Nuuk flights from Keflavík.

There are no ferries to Greenland, only between ports within Greenland.